# TabActivity not work in Android?

Tags: android, checkbox, tabactivity

I have 3 tab in my Tab Activity.in second tab one check box is present if check box is checked true mean enable the third tab layout content otherwise disable the layout content.How to do this pls help me.I try some is not work.

this my code:

Second tab.activity:

```
resistent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(resistent.isChecked()==true)
                {
                    AuthenticationConstant.residentenable=true;//is boolean value
                }
                else
                {
                    AuthenticationConstant.residentenable=false;
                }

            }
        });
```

third tab.activity:

```
public void layoutfunction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (AuthenticationConstant.residentenable) {
            rlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            rlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```